# How to install a file in app data in setup project (C#)

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project, app-data

I want to install my database to a separate folder (@ C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Company1\database.mdb)

I'm using a C# setup project.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Right-click on the project and select View -> File System
2. in the new File System screen, right-click the root node (File System on target Machine) and select Add Special Folder -> User's Application Data Folder
3. Select the newly added folder form the treeview and create any sub-folder structure you need
4. Finally select your destination folder, right-click, Add -> File and select the .mddb file.

Comment: I tried that but got
File '<file>' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users
No sign of my database anywhere in the app data folder/ subfolders

Comment: It does work I thought that when i right clicked and install that it automatically re generated the setup file but no.

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness, here is the official documentation for changing the folders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/716bxh4e(v=vs.100)

> 1. To add a custom folder that targets a predefined Windows folder In the folder list of the File System Editor, select the File System on
>    Target Machine node.
> 2. On the Action menu, point to Add Special Folder, and then click Custom Folder. The new folder is highlighted in the folder list.
> 3. Type a name for the custom folder. For example, to target the Temp folder, type "Temp Folder".
> 4. In the Properties window, select the DefaultLocation property and enter the Windows Installer system folder property for the folder you
>    wish to target. For example, the property for the Temp folder is
>    [TempFolder]. For a list of system folder properties supported by
>    Windows Installer, see System Folder Properties.

Here is a list of all folder properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa372057(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [**AdminToolsFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367543(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the directory that contains administrative tools. |
| [**AppDataFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367565(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Roaming** folder for the current user. |
| [**CommonAppDataFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992(v=vs.85)) | The full path to application data for all users. |
| [**CommonFiles64Folder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367993(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the predefined **64-bit Common Files** folder. |
| [**CommonFilesFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367994(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Common Files** folder for the current user. |
| [**DesktopFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368276(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Desktop** folder. |
| [**FavoritesFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368578(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Favorites** folder for the current user. |
| [**FontsFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368605(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Fonts** folder. |
| [**LocalAppDataFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369768(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the folder that contains local (nonroaming) applications. |
| [**MyPicturesFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370527(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Pictures** folder. |
| [**PersonalFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370806(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Documents** folder for the current user. |
| [**ProgramFiles64Folder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370880(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the predefined **64-bit Program Files** folder. |
| [**ProgramFilesFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370881(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the predefined **32-bit Program Files** folder. |
| [**ProgramMenuFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370882(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Program Menu** folder. |
| [**SendToFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371615(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **SendTo** folder for the current user. |
| [**StartMenuFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372025(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Start menu** folder. |
| [**StartupFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372027(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Startup** folder. |
| [**System16Folder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372053(v=vs.85)) | The full path to folder for 16-bit system DLLs. |
| [**System64Folder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372054(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the predefined **System64** folder. |
| [**SystemFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372055(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **System** folder for the current user. |
| [**TempFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372067(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Temp** folder. |
| [**TemplateFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372069(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Template** folder for the current user. |
| [**WindowsFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372816(v=vs.85)) | The full path to the **Windows** folder. |
| [**WindowsVolume**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372817(v=vs.85)) | The volume of the **Windows** folder. |

When using them, make sure to use the square brackets [] around the property names.

Comment: You really should add the most relevant parts of your linked resources to your answer. Web resources change sooner or later and might not be available any longer. This is very true for Microsoft pages.

Comment: @Andreas I have added the related information as you suggested, to make the answer complete.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on your Setup project -> View -> File System. Then you could add a custom folder and set its default location to `[CommonAppDataFolder]`:

[image]

Then add your database file to this folder.

Comment: My database file is not in there

Comment: I've viewed the folder by modified date and there's nothing new

Comment: It works, in program data folder but not in app data folder. 
Thanks for your help