# LocalDB location

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using LocalDB and Entity Framework code-first for a new project. I want to change the location where the database is created/saved. However, every time I do, I get one of any number of exceptions. If I try adding `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf`, I get an exception stating:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

As well as:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Projects\database.mdf' as database 'Schema.MyProject'.

Eventually, when I run this program on another computer, I'm looking to create/save the database in the AppData folder. How can this be done?

Comment: If you save database to your appdata folder, not all users may be able to access it.

Comment: @msmolcic92: That's the point with this particular application.

Comment: Try with this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354594/how-to-install-a-file-in-app-data-in-setup-project-c

Comment: @msmolcic92:I'm not to the install point yet. I'm just trying to get set the default location right now.